# Create access token without expiry time in Spring Authorization Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I am working on Spring Authorization Server 1.0.0 and want to create access token without expiry time via /oauth2/token API.

I tried set to expiry time as 0 in  TokenSettings.builder as below

```
 TokenSettings.builder()
                .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ZERO)
                .build();
```

However it doesnt allow and fails with
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: accessTokenTimeToLive must be greater than Duration.ZERO

Answer (score 0):

try using `Duration.ofSeconds(Long.MAX_VALUE)`

from Duration class

*A physical duration could be of infinite length. For practicality, the duration is stored with constraints similar to Instant. The duration uses nanosecond resolution with a maximum value of the seconds that can be held in a long. This is greater than the current estimated age of the universe.*

Comment: Thanks for sharing this but doesnt work. When I try, it throws the exception - 
java.time.DateTimeException: Instant exceeds minimum or maximum instant
 at java.base/java.time.Instant.create(Instant.java:413) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.time.Instant.ofEpochSecond(Instant.java:332) ~[na:na].....